# Email Sending as System Hostname

Tags: magento2, email

I'm running Magento CE 2.2.4.

When the system sends any emails, they send as the webserver's hostname. I'm not sure where/what handles sending emails, but it seems its missing the from address.

I have contacts setup under Store Email Addresses, but they seem to be ignored.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sales emails are sent from a strange email #15458

> I am using magento 2.2.4 on go daddy VPS.I have configured the store
>   email addresses properly and also select in sales->sales emails.
>   Whenever an order is placed customer recieves order confirmation mail
>   in spam folder which is due to strange email send address(Email From).
>   I am not using any custom SMTP extension this is a fresh magento
>   installed

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15458
```

**Possible fix:**

```
#14952 Confirmation emails have no FROM or FROM email address 2.2.4 #15119
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/15119

```
Confirmation emails have no FROM or FROM email address 2.2.4 #14952
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952